# Why I call 'eth_call' all returns '0x'?

Tags: contract-development, parity

I write a simple contract to test my Parity jsonRPC.
Here is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract test01 {
  string key;
  string name;
  function test01() {
    // constructor
  }
  function readKey(string p) constant returns(string) {
    key = p;
    return key;
  }
  function readName(string p) constant returns(string) {
    name = p;
    return name;
  }
}
```

I read some document and know that I should use the first 4 bytes of function name to call a function.

I write it on Remix so that I can get the function bytes directly.
Just as this picture show:
[image]

So I use the jsonRPC `eth_call` to call the functoin `readKey`. And put the parameter behind the four bytes.

Just like this command:

```
curl --data '{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"data":"0x19efb2b30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005"}],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST 10.4.20.69:8540
```

But it just return `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x","id":1}`

And I change some other parameters. But it still return `0x`. I don't understand why. Maybe because I don't call jsonRPC in a correct way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the encoding of the string

> 19efb2b3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

With your contract abi you can use the site https://abi.hashex.org/ to create the data parameter of your call.

Comment: do you know what the `0x` returned signifies?

Comment: It prefix used to denote the data is in hexadecimal format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-numbers-prefixed-with-0x.

Comment: okay I get it. The returned value in this case is empty. 0x is just always prepended. I would have preferred returning null instead of just 0x but I dont make the rules :)